# How to get the thead values of column header of full calendar

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

[image]I am using the full calendar week view in angular 7 application. I need to retrieve the values which are visible on week selection of full calendar.
Any quick help is really helpful!

Comment: Did you inspect the HTML to see if there was a way to I'd identify them, e.g. using CSS selectors and/or position in the DOM? What have you tried?

Comment: i checked it. You mean to say the getting values from the table div class or id? I didn't try in that way. But my concern is if we have any default method from full-calender it makes more sense.

Comment: If i am sure no predefined method in full-calendar then i will try in that way.

Comment: Well if you study https://fullcalendar.io/docs you will indeed see that fullCalendar doesn't provide a way to do that. The closest you can get is to [get information about the current view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-view) which includes the start/end dates, but from that you would still have to calculate the individual days between those

Comment: <th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-sun fc-past" data-date="2019-07-28"><span>Sun 7/28</span></th> 
Need to get this values in my ts file data-date="2019-07-28".
Please find screenshot attached.

Answer (score 1):

Really I don't know waht are you looking for, but I can not resist to tell something about how select an HTML element with a class

If we want select an HTML element with a class in Angular, we can use a work around that is create a directive with selector the class of this element. Usually I write this directive in the own component.ts -don't forget declare in module the directive!!-

e.g.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '.fc-day-header',
})
export class DayHeaderDirective {
}
```

So, in our component we can use ViewChildren to get theses element, and in ngAfterViewInit, we can see this

```
  @ViewChildren(DayHeaderDirective,{read:ElementRef}) ths:QueryList<ElementRef>
  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    this.ths.forEach(x=>{
      console.log(x.nativeElement.innerHTML)
    })
  }
```

Comment: I am not getting anything in logs. Can you please check once again?

Comment: Can you see my latest comment above. Please see if you can help to get that?

Comment: Has you declare the directive in your module?

Comment: Added in providers [ DayHeaderDirective] of app module. Is it fine?

Comment: the directives goes in `[declarations]`, [providers] are mainly for services